# AppleScript handling dialogues when putting files back Trash

Tags: applescript, put, back, recycle-bin

I have a simple script to take items out of the trash and put them back into their original directory:

```
repeat 10 times 
    tell application "Finder" to open trash 
    tell application "Finder" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            delay 0.2 
            key code 125 
            key down command 
            delay 0.2 
            key code 51         
            key up command      
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 0.2 
    tell application "Finder" to close every window 
end repeat
```

But running this script throws up an exception - a finder dialogue pops up saying the file already exists in the original location, with 3 options: 'Keep both', 'stop'and 'replace'. I'd like the script to automatically select 'replace'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to face several issues:

The last location of the file is stored inside trash .ds_store. For some files (if original folder is deleted) the path will not exist in that file and the put back option will not work (so your script will not) - youll see it greyed out in the context menu if you try it manually.

Then the key press gui methods will not return anything - so you cant control further steps like overwrite files.

The best approach imho is to read out the original locations, then create move commands with overwrite options.

On another thread someone wrote a pearl script to do that: https://superuser.com/a/867988

Run the script like

```
set ps to "posixpath/to/script.pl"
set moveCommands to do shell script "perl " & quoted form of ps
```

Then execute all move commands with do shell script like above. Best thing is you can chsnge the script to add options like do not overwrite if exists "mv -n". I didnt test the script just read through it. You may be able to pipe the commands so you can do it all in less steps.

Note that this will work for files where the original folder exists. If you have different situations you need to tweak it so folders get created

Answer (score 0):

This works for me running the latest version of OSX Sierra.  You may need to adjust some of the Delay settings to work for you

```
tell application "Finder"
    close every window
    activate
    open trash
    select every item of trash
    delay 1
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    key code 51 using (command down)
    delay 1
    try
        set theCheckbox to checkbox "Apply to All" of scroll area 1 of window "Copy" of application process "Finder"
        set applyToAll to perform action "AXPress" of checkbox "Apply to All" of scroll area 1 of window "Copy" of application process "Finder"
        set replaceButton to perform action "AXPress" of button "Replace" of scroll area 1 of window "Copy" of application process "Finder"
        if theCheckbox exists then
            delay 1
            applyToAll
            delay 1
            replaceButton
        else
            key code 51 using (command down)
        end if
    end try
end tell
```